# ¿Quiénes serían los "piggybackers" y los "tailgaters"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

Hoy leí un cartel en la oficina que prevenía sobre los "tailgaters" y los "piggybackers". Decía algo así como

> "Piggybacking" or "tailgating" is when an unauthorized person enters a restricted area, such as the office space, by following or accompanying an authorized employee.

Básicamente en mi oficina (como en muchas otras) usamos una tarjeta RFID para identificarnos al acceder. El cartel previene sobre esa gente que entra en la oficina sin necesidad de acercar la tarjeta al lector para autenticarse porque aprovechan que alguien abre la puerta para ellos. Muchas veces es algo legítimo (le sujetamos la puerta por cortesía a alguien o dejamos pasar a alguien que dice haberse olvidado la tarjeta) pero también en una estratagema de *ingeniería social* que permite entre el 40 al 60% de los accesos no autorizados.

[*Piggyback*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piggyback) es llevar a alguien a hombros o a caballito, aunque también es un término referido al acceso a una red inalámbrica de internet con el propio ordenador del intruso dentro de la red de otra conexión inalámbrica, sin el permiso o el conocimiento explícito de suscriptor. En el ejemplo del cartel el sentido es más "físico" que figurado, aunque nadie entra realmente "a caballito" o sobre tus hombros.

[*Tailgate* o *tailgating*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailgating) es conducir tu vehículo muy cerca de otro sin respetar la distancia de seguridad.

El matiz en el texto es que el "piggybacker" puede entrar porque explícitamente se lo permites mientras que el tailgater "aprovecha" tu descuido y trata de pasar pegadito a ti.

Aunque hay una traducción para "*piggyback*" (ir a caballito o a hombros) no es la que yo usaría para traducir el texto de ejemplo. Para traducir "tailgate/tailgating" no se me ocurre un término, solo describir la acción.

¿Existe en español un término que pueda usarse en estos contextos para describir esa acción de ir muy pegado a alguien y aprovechar esa circunstancia en favor propio?

Comment: Quizás *pegarse* a alguien.

Answer (score 7):

¿Acaso no es lo mismo que un colado? Alguien que, aprovechándose de las circunstancias que lo rodean, ingresa de forma irregular a algún lugar.

Comment: "Colado" es una palabra de uso habitual en Chile.

Comment: "Colado" es una palabra de uso habitual en México