# Is caballito the exact equivalent of piggyback?

Tags: definiciones

According to this question by Diego [¿Quiénes serían los "piggybackers" y los "tailgaters"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21440/qui%c3%a9nes-ser%c3%adan-los-piggybackers-y-los-tailgaters) the practice of carrying a child on your shoulders is called *caballito* in Spanish. To quote him

> llevar a alguien a hombros o a caballito,

But the [DLE definition](https://dle.rae.es/caballito?m=form) states as its first definition

> Juego para entretener a un niño, que consiste en sentarlo sobre las rodillas e imitar el trote o galope del caballo.

which unless I have misunderstood uses the word for knee not shoulders. Have I misunderstood the dictionary?

The reason I am interested is because I was trying to establish whether piggyback was a cultural universal as I am reviewing a scientific paper which uses it and I am interested in how widely it would be understood.

Comment: Yo voy a decir que sí. Creo que esa entrada del diccionario recoge "**hacer** el caballito", tanto para la primera de lo de las rodillas como la segunda sobre una moto. No explica "llevar a caballito" (para llevar sobre el lomo), ni como entrada ni como locución adverbial. Ahora, la mayoría de los traductores traducen "piggyback" como [llevar a caballito](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=llevar%20a%20caballito)

Answer (score 1):

In Mexico (in the state I live in) we use the expression "cargar de caballito" or "llevar de caballito". In other states people use other expressions such as: *a mamanche*, *de camachito*, *de pilonche*, *hacer cuch*, *a camiachi*, and many others. All of them with the same meaning.

You can see more words for *piggyback* used in different parts of Mexico in this tweet: https://twitter.com/Lauentuiter/status/1050437042742661120